# Install iPhone SDK DMG file on iMac but I can't find where any of the programs are located

Tags: macos, iphone, installation, sdk, dmg-image

I just download the iPhone SDK disk image from Apple and installed in on my new iMac (by following these directions: [link text](http://www.ofzenandcomputing.com/zanswers/779)).
The problem is, I can't seem to find where any of the programs got installed. I can't find XCode or Interface Builder in the applications list and everytime I click on the "iPhone SDK" icon in the applications list, it re-opens finder with the same packages that I am trying to install.

**P/S:**
I am completely new to the the Mac world so I might be doing everything completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SDK applications should be located in the /developer folder. Just hit in Finder your hard drive name, and hit 'developer' folder. There, all the application are.

And you probably went too fast trough the installation process (somewhere at where to install it to). You would've known if you didn't went so fast.

P/S: if you're completely new to Mac, you shouldn't be trying to work on the iPhone SDK, you need some Mac knowledge as the iPhone OS looks like the Mac OS.